# mysql out parameter for procedure not showing

Tags: mysql, parameters, out

I've created a procedure where I have 2 in parameters and 1 out parameter. However, I don't know why my output doesn't want to come out. I don't want to use a select statement. I would like to use the out parameter. Thanks.

```
create procedure quiz_totals(in q1 double unsigned, in q2 double unsigned, out p_total int)
begin
declare v_ceil_q1 int;
declare v_ceil_q2 int;
declare v_max int;
declare v_min int;

set v_ceil_q1 := ceiling(q1);
set v_ceil_q2 := ceiling(q2);

create table temp_tbl(t_scores int); 
insert into temp_tbl(t_scores) values(v_ceil_q1), (v_ceil_q2));

select max(t_scores) into v_max from temp_tbl;
select min(t_scores) into v_min from temp_tbl;

set p_total := (v_ceil_q1) + (v_ceil_q2) +  v_max - 2*v_min;

drop table temp_tbl;
end;
#
delimiter ;
call quiz_totals(23, 32.4, @total);
```

This is my output:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

No p_total ! Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a select, even if you don't want to...

```
SELECT @total;
```

If you wanna see what's inside !